# Re-creating a 'contact data based' event in welcome journey

Tags: trigger, journeybuilder

I'm trying to re-create a welcome journey 'contact data' event as this feature is apparently phasing out in a future release.

The problem with data-based events is that it only uses 'date' attributes and we use an attribute with a 'text' format, as we only collect the month each customer was born.

Does anyone know what would the best avenue be to re-create this within a welcome journey?

[image]